# How to modify a variable using async method before it use in widget build?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, build, widget, future

I have a variable named `userName`,which depends on databse query,so async is a must.
My older code can be concluded liks this

```
class IndexScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexScreenState createState() => _IndexScreenState();
}

//use database query function
Future<void> initUser() async{
  UserTable().getUserInfo(curUserEmail).then((value)=>null);
}

//show page
class _IndexScreenState extends State<IndexScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initUser().then((value){
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () =>router.navigateTo(context, '/welcome'),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
//The static global variable is used in Body in other files
            body: Body()
        ),
      ),
    );
  });
}
}
```

It warns that miss `return`,I dont knwo how to amend my code.

Thanks!!

Comment: why shouldn't you use FutureBuilder? It will be helpful to load the screen like you want after completed the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by using the `FutureBuilder` widget. Please refer the code below.

```dart
class IndexScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexScreenState createState() => _IndexScreenState();
}

//use database query function
Future<Map> initUser() async {
  final data =
      await UserTable().getUserInfo(curUserEmail);
  return data;
}

//show page
class _IndexScreenState extends State<IndexScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initUser(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final theme = Theme.of(context);
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () => router.navigateTo(context, '/welcome'),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                body: Body(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          // Returns empty container untill the data is loaded
          Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Should it be "else{ return Container();}"?  I run this code but it shows black screen which I think is Container(),but the initUser() function has finished,it didn't change.I doubt it's for my gteUserInfo() method retrun nothing,it just assign values to static variables

Comment: I have updated the code snippets. Can you please check with the current code snippet and revert back?

Comment: I watch `snapshot.connectionState` to fix my special bug,thanks!!